# How to show images from s3?

Tags: python, django

I'm finishing an application by django that generates pdf certificates
it was working great before I pull it into heroke and set up S3 amazom to host static files.
I have an html with the certificate template, and by HTML2PDF I render it to pdf. But it's not showing the background by css, it works just in the tag

Weird that if we opent the image url in s3 amazom it's shown perfectly

here the template css part

```
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        {% load static %}
        <style type="text/css">
                @page {
                    size: 1122.52px 1587.4px ;
                    /*size: A4 landscape;*/
                    margin: 0cm;
                    background-image: url({{bg_front}});
                    height: 1588;
                }
        </style>
```

My view:

```
class ViewPDF(View):

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = {}
    pdf = True
    if kwargs['pk']:
        try:                    
            participant = Participant.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
            print(participant.cpf)
            if participant.name:
                certificate = Certificate.objects.get(pk=participant.certificate.pk)

                pathBack = str(certificate.template.template_back.url)

                pathFront = str(certificate.template.template_front.url)
                print(pathFront)
                #
                # CONFIGURA OS BACKGROUNDS E TEXTO
                #
                data['bg_front'] = pathFront
                data['bg_back'] = pathBack
                setting = certificate.template.settings         
                start_date = datetime.strftime(certificate.start_date,'%d/%m/%Y')
                end_date = datetime.strftime(certificate.start_date,'%d/%m/%Y')
                data['text_front'] = setting.replace('<<nome>>',participant.name).replace('<<cpf>>',str(participant.cpf)).replace('<<ch>>',str(certificate.ch)).replace('<<instituicao>>',str(certificate.institution)).replace('<<DataInicio>>',start_date).replace('<<DataFim>>',end_date)
                data['cpf'] = participant.cpf
            pdf = render_to_pdf('app_certificates/body_front_pdf.html', data)
            return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
except TypeError as e:
    return HttpResponse(e)
```

Comment: You're printing `pathFront`, what does it show? Add that to your question. Also explain what `certificate.template.template_front` is, is it an uploaded file via a file field? If so, what are your settings for `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL`?

Comment: Also, open your browser debug tools and look at the error you see there. If the background isn't shown, there is a 404 error. Look at the url in the error.

Comment: pathFront is the path of the image uploaded by the user... now it's on S3 Amazon  The certificate.template.template_front is the url image background I want in the css background

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'app_certificates','media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

Comment: Do I have to change the MEDIA_ROOT or something to match the S3 Amazom???

Comment: I tried to replace background-image: url({{bg_front}}) for background: url( '{{bg_front}}' ) but doesnt work either

Comment: I got this message error in the terminal: Could not process uri: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Comment: Please look at your browser dev tools, the error shown there and the url it's trying to fetch!

Comment: And I don't understand how it can be on S3, unless you've changed your storage (are you using django-storages) and changed `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` setting? If so, show it.

Comment: Yep. I've set the DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE occurs that the image loads perfectly if I call it from a tag <img src> for example, but, in backgroun it doesn't work

Comment: on Dev Tools Browser nothing is shown cause it's a PDF page

Comment: Try rendering to an html page in your browser instead of pdf first. So you can check the problem. Normally, a url in css is relative to the css itself or absolute. If the url doesn't start with `https://yourbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/...` or something like that then it won't work. But also, you still didn't answer my question: what does `print(pathFront)` show?

Comment: I solved turning the templates folder in my s3 public that's alright now... Thank You so much